# spinner and onItemSelected

Tags: android

If I have 2 spinner depended with  type  ArrayList>

```
 spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                         ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
                        for (HashMap<String, String> map2 : arrList) {
                            String value = map2.get("SectionID");
                            // Do something

                            Context context = getApplicationContext();

                            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, value, duration);
                            toast.show();
                        Log.d("wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww: ", value);
                        // Do something
                    }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter) {

                    }
                });
```

i do like this but kothing happend and logcat not having error

Comment: i do not understand you can u explain ... i mean i will get the position then the course id

Comment: does your arraylist have one hashmap at each index with only one key-value pair?

Comment: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262871/android-two-spinner-onitemselected?rq=1

Comment: my array list is coursesList and do this   map.put(TAG_CourseID, CourseID);
      map.put(TAG_Name, Name);

      // adding HashList to ArrayList
      coursesList.add(map);

Comment: can you help me more the example is different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I do not know how to get the item with tag (courseid) in this array after the user click the item in spinner.

If you only want to get the `courseid` from each row, you do not need a custom OnItemSelectedListener. Simple use:

```
// Let's use the regular listener     vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
        HashMap<String, String> map = arrList.get(position);
        String id = map.get("courseid");
        // Do something
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter) {}
});
```

Where `arrList` is the class variable that holds the data for your SimpleAdapter.

---

> i do like this but kothing happend and logcat not having error

That is because you just created `arrList`, so it is *empty*:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
for (HashMap<String, String> map2 : arrList) { // This arrList has no data!
```

You need to use the ArrayList that you used when you created your SimpleAdapter.

```
new SimpleAdapter(this, arrList, ...);
```

This is the ArrayList you **must** use and it **must** be a class variable.

Comment: and what i write in class CustomOnItemSelectedListene ?

Comment: You are not using adding any special features, so you don't need to use CustomOnItemSelectedListener. You can use the regular OnItemSelectedListener.

Answer (score 0):

Your post is a little hard to understand, but i think i have an idea. you have a single spinner populated by an arraylist with multiple hashmaps at each index for each "rung" on the spinner. So when the item is selected, you want to get the single key that is selected and do something with it. Well as we know, a `hashMap` isn't really indexed so we have to use alternative methods to get at it, correct?

```
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                // for each key in the hashMap at this position..
                for (String key : arrList.get(position).keySet()) {
                    if (key == "Calculus") {
//                      do something
                    } else if (key == "Physics") {
//                      do something else
                    }
                }                                       
            }
```

The idea is really simple here. you get the entire keySet of the hashMap at the index of the position selected on the spinner and you do something for each key in it, depending on what it says. This should work without too much hassle, assuming you only have one key-value pair there.

**BUT** I have to say that you should really re-think the design a bit. You have multiple hashMap containers just holding one thing each. It really is a waste of resources. it's hard to recommend an alternative because i don't exactly know how this data is being used, but you should know that making objects in java isn't free.

Comment: i do as you said but i change it to for (String key : arrList.get(position).get("courseid")) and there is an error  can only over an array or an instance of java.lang.iterable

Comment: if you leave it as is- perhaps change "Calculus" to "courseid", it will work. your problem is that you're trying to get a key (String in this case) and this is not iterable. What the code does is get *all* the keys (regardless of how many) and iterate through them for a specific key. Doing it your way isn't the best if the key "courseid" is only in one index of the arrayList, unless you specifically want to know if it's there.