# my spinner and how to get the position of item selected

Tags: android

i have a spinner populated by an arraylist with multiple hashmaps at each index for each "rung" on the spinner. So when the item is selected, i want to get the single key that is selected and do something with it 
i do like this in my pic but there is a problem 
how can i solve it

[image http://www.qzal.net/01/2012-10/13530999521.png](http://www.qzal.net/01/2012-10/13530999521.png)

Here is a usable copy of the code:

```
spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        // for each key in the hashMap at this position..
        for (String key : arrList.get(position).get("SectionID"))
        {
        }
    }                                      

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter) {}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must do this one level at a time. First fetch each HashMap from your ArrayList, then ask for your specific key:

```
for (HashMap<String, String> map : arrList) {
    String value = map.get("SectionID");
    // Do something
}
```

However if you just initialized `arrList` there won't be anything in it...

Comment: thanks but i have do like spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener() { so what sould i do at CustomOnItemSelectedListener ? the same or

Comment: Since this question is strictly about getting a specific value from each HashMap. Let's discuss which listener to use in [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13423378/1267661).

Comment: ok i do as you said i i try ro change my code can you try to help me

Comment: I just posted an answer in the other question. See you there.