# Connecting the item of one spinner to another spinner list in android studio

Tags: android-spinner

Am totally a novice/beginner in android studio,I have a project to deal with.But am stuck at one particular area.My concept is creating a convocation app for my university,first of all in first layout i just created two spinners.First one is for names and other one is for departments,the thing is by choosing a particular department from the spinner list,the eligible candidate in that particular department for convocation must be displayed in the name spinner list likewise by choosing different departments different set of names must be displayed in the name spinner list.

Please help me to solve this !! It will be helpful for my future projects !! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can recognize the particular spinner using its`R.id` and then in the `OnItemSelectedListener` you can set the contents of other spinner using currently selected item in initial spinner 
See this question [Android: two Spinner onItemSelected()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262871/android-two-spinner-onitemselected)