# how do i put 2 spinners on 1 activity with same options?

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

firstly I'm a newbie to using this program so any help is appreciated. I need spinner 1 to show 7 cities the user can choose from and spinner 2 to show the same 7 cities that the user can select.

I have some code below but my tutor says it's wrong and it won't work for the second spinners I tried to find a way but can seem to do so

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Cities, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    String text = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)


{

}

}
```

spinner 1 is meant to be the start destination and spinner 2 is meant to be the destination they are going to. once the user selects the options it tells them the distance from spinner 1 to spinner 2.( the distances are already given to us in a table)

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9263046/7666442 you will get hint how use same `setOnItemSelectedListener()` for multiple `spinner`

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains only one spinner.

```
Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
```

Define one more spinner in XML and assign the same adapter to new spinner and set a separate `OnItemSelectedListener` each spinner.

Get the values(city names) from each spinner and calculate the distance.